# Windows Service with Task Parallel Library, N number of Tasks with it's own timer

Tags: c#

I am new with Task Parallel Library.
I have a windows service that is running sync, connecting to N number of database sequentially which is running fine.
The down side of it, it has to wait for the queue to finish before connecting to another instance of the database.
How do I get each connection running in it's own thread and it's own timer.
Thanks.

```
//Configuration class
public class Config
{ 
  public string Profile { get; set; }
  public string Connection { get; set; }
  public int interval {get; set;}
  public bool isEnabled {get; set;}
}

//Worker class
public class Worker 
{
  Config _config; 
  bool IsCompleted = false; 
  Timer timer = new Timer();

  public Worker()
  {} 

  public Worker(Config config)
  {
    _config = config; 
    timer.interval = _config.interval;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

  }

  public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
        //To avoid collision, if previous process is not yet finish.                        
        if (!IsComplated)
        { 
          return;
        }


        //Calling Method to sync data.
        ....
        ....            
        IsComplated = true; 

        //refresh config, if disabled than stop the timer.
        _config = RefreshConfig(_config);   
        if (!_config.IsEnabled)
        {
           StopTimer();
        }
  }

  public void StartWorking()
  {
    //Switch on timer;
    timer.Start();
  }

  private void StopTimer()
  {
       timer.Stop();
       timer.Enabled = false;
  }
```

}

```
  //The main service thread.
  public class myService:ServiceBase
  {
      List<Config> configs;
      public myService()
      {
         //Download configurations
         Configs = DownloadConfigurations()
      }

      protected override void OnStart(string[] args) 
      {
         if (configs.Length > 0)
         {
            //Run in Sync, How do I create N number of thread base on N                      number of configs
            foreach(Config _config in configs)
            {
               Worker doWork = new Worker(_config); 
               StartWorking();
            }
         }
      }

      private List<Config> DownloadConfigurations()
      {
          //Method to return Configurations
          List<Config> configurations = new List<Config>();
          ....
          ....
          return configurations; 

      }
  }
```

Comment: It would depend on whether the server can handle more connections - example SQL express has limited connection. if you need to make the connection thread specific, do so. Its your code.

Comment: Does your database driver expose asynchronous endpoints?

Comment: @BugFinder & Yuval Itzchakov, It won't connect to the same server simultaneously, what I want is connecting to different server simultaneously without waiting for the thread to finish.

Comment: then you need to add more detail to your question we cannot guess, theres no code, no technical info on what you're connecting to.. most dbs these days handle multiple connections, heck even access does that.  But the sentement still stands if you need to connect to different things in different threads - do so, its your code

Comment: @BugFinder, I know it's my own code :D, I will post some basic concept on what I am trying to achieve..